# Non-linear optimization in python

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I'm trying to create an algorithm in python to solve a seating chart problem.

The formalized problem is as follows :
[image]
[image]

To solve it my idea was to use a linear solver, however the objective function is not linear. Indeed, the matrix R which is multiplied by A depends also on A.

So I thought of solving it with a non linear solver. But here I am lost, none of them seems to take the same formalism. Namely:

`

```
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cp
#Data
PEOPLE = 6
TABLES = 3
SIZE_TABLES= 2

score = np.matrix([[0, 5, 3, 2, 10, 9],
[10, 0, 3, 2, 10, 9],
[8, 5, 0, 2, 10, 9],
[0, 5, 3, 0, 10, 9],
[20, 5, 3, 2, 0, 9],
[15, 5, 3, 2, 10, 0]]
                 )

weight = np.ones((6,1))

#variable
a = cp.Variable((PEOPLE, TABLES), boolean=True)

#constraints
constraints = [
    max(np.sum(a, axis=1))==1,
    np.max(np.dot(a,weight),axis=0)<=SIZE_TABLES
]

#Objective
objective = np.sum(np.dot(score, a) * a)


problem = cp.Problem(cp.Maximize(objective), constraints)


probleme.solve(solver=???)
print(a)
```

Do you know a non-linear solver to solve this type of problem?

Comment: I believe the affinity matrix S should have size n,n, not n,m?

Comment: Also, when you paste code into a question on StackOverflow, please make your code a [mre]. In particular in python, please add all the relevant `import` at the beginning of the code. We can guess that there is `import numpy as np`, but it's harder to guess which constraint programming module you imported to get `cp`, `Problem` and `Variable`.

Comment: Yes sry for the import, the matrix S should have size n,n indeed.

Comment: Anyway, it looks like your constraints are linear and your objective is quadratic, so a quadratic solver should be able to solve this. You just need to rewrite `sum_j sum_i A(i,j)*R(i,j)` into a more standard form `a^T M a` for some matrix `M`, where `a` is matrix `A` seen as a vector.

Comment: Thanks Stef, do you recommend a particular quadratic solver ?

Comment: Since you're using cvxpy, you can try with any of the solvers directly available, as long as they are designed to solve quadratic problems (probably abbreviated as "QP" in their documentation)

Comment: Use an MIQP solver or linearize the objective (possible because we multiply by binary variables).